# How to check if index includes a particular column in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, indexing

I want my app to add a column to an existing index if that column hasn't already been added to the index.

Is there a way to test if the column exists in the index, or am I better off dropping and rebuilding the entire index including the new column?

Cheers guys.

Comment: SHOW INDEX FROM [table_name] where Column_name=[column_name] works for mySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about the columns in an index, use [PRAGMA index_info](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_index_info).